# Bar chart looks bad before change data

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart, flot

Hi here I set the data to the bar chart:

```
 setDatosBarra: function(data){ //
    
    var self = this;
    var horaEstim = 0;
    var horaReal = 0;
    var horaTotal = 0;

    if(data[0].horas_estim != '-'){
        horaEstim = data[0].horas_estim;
    }
    if(data[0].horas_real != '-'){
        horaReal = data[0].horas_real;
    }
    if(data[0].total_horas != '-'){
        horaTotal = data[0].total_horas;
    }
    var datosBarra =[{data: [[0,horaEstim]], color: "#691717"}, {data: [[1,horaReal]], color: "#173D69"},{data: [[2,horaTotal]], color: "#176469"}];

    self.flotLinea(datosBarra);
},
```

When all is ready I send the data to `self.flotBar`;

This is the `flotBar` function:

```
flotBar: function(datos){

     var self = this;
    
    if(datos == 0){
      var data = [["SIN REGISTROS",0]];
    }else{
      var data = datos;

    }

    function getTooltip(label, x, y) {
        return "<strong style='font-size:18px;'> " + y + " </strong> horas"; 
    }

    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder",data, {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.3,
                align: "center",
                lineWidth: 0,
                fill:.75
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: [[0,"Horas estimadas"],[1,"Horas reales"],[2,"Total horas"]],
            mode: "categories",
            tickLength: 0
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        },


        tooltip: true,

            tooltipOpts : {
                content : getTooltip,
                defaultTheme : false
        },
    });

 
},
```

Ok , and this is my problem, example:

I select a option in an dropDown:

[image]

And the bar chart looks like this:

[image]

If I select other option in the dropDown:

[image]

The bar chart looks like this:

[image]

And if I select again the first option "Correcion de errores", the bar chart looks like this:

[image]

So.. always the first time that I show the bar chart looks like in the first image , with the numbers in the line, but If I select other option looks good.
I need see good the bar chart always and no just when I select other option.
I'm using flot javascript library.
How can I fix this? sorry by my english

Comment: You call `flotLinea()` instead of `flotBar()` in your first code. Is this the same function? Could you maybe put all of your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the question as stated is that we do not have all the code. In essence, you should either provide all the code, or shrink down the problem to something that shows the issue and then, well, provide all the code. As far as I can guess, you have some other code somewhere else that is drawing the initial chart. The second and subsequent times? Drawn properly. To support my assertion, notice that in your initial image the captions for the x-axis tick markers (ditto the bars themselves) are *right aligned* not centered.

For fun, I wrote a quick jsFiddle that showed [how to switch datasets](https://jsfiddle.net/JMBucknall/nsg58g3c/) using a button (much as you want to do with the drop-down) and redraw the chart:

```
    drawChart = function(index) {
        var chartData = getDataForChart(rawData[index]);
        if (chart) {
            chart.setData(chartData);
            chart.draw();
        }
        else {
            chart = $.plot("#barchart", chartData, chartOptions);
       }
    },
    switchDataset = function() {
        datasetIndex = (datasetIndex + 1) % datasetCount;            
        drawChart(datasetIndex);
    };

$("#switchButton").on("click", switchDataset);
```

Because I decided to load new data into the chart rather than redraw it all from scratch (to be honest I saw no real difference either way), it meant that I had to pre-calculate the maximum value for the y-axis:

```
    calcValueMax = function() {
        var max = 0;
        rawData.forEach(function(values) {
            values.forEach(function(value) {
                if (value > max) {
                    max = value;
                }
            });
        });
        return max;
    },
    // other code
    chartOptions.yaxis.max = calcValueMax();
```

Hope that helps.